# Get start and end index of word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to get the start index and end index of words in a text:
as input i have  :

```
text= "Hello, this red car is very beautiful and nice. Also, this car is green."
words_list= ["car" , "red","green"]
```

i want to get the start index and end index of those words in the text please..

Comment: Did you try [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.index)?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Since you have not yet researched the algorithm nor attempted to code the problem yourself, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: It seems that  you're missing the basic units of string processing.  This would mean that you need to work through a tutorial or two; Stack Overflow is not an appropriate vehicle for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

text= "Hello, this red car is very beautiful and nice. Also, this car is green."
words_list= ["car" , "red","green"]

for word in words_list:
    for m in re.finditer(word,text):
        print (m.group(),m.start(), m.end())
```

output:

```
car 16 19
car 59 62
red 12 15
green 66 71
```

Or with:

```
print ("key:",m.group(),"start:",m.start(),"end:",m.end())
```

Output:

```
key: car start: 16 end: 19
key: car start: 59 end: 62
key: red start: 12 end: 15
key: green start: 66 end: 71
```

Comment: thank you very much ! but  for the word "car" , there is another in the text but you method return only the first

Comment: Does not match numbers properly : `Dispute Case ID MM-Z-9999999999 the amount of $29.98 should be AU dollars total is $62.85 US dollars.`  `words_list=[$29.98,$62.85]

Answer (score 0):

While Synthase is correct, there is also a way to do it without importing any modules. This is how I would do it:

```python
text= "Hello, this red car is very beautiful and nice. Also, this car is green."
words_list= ["car" , "red","green"]


for word in words_list:
    if word in text:
        start_index = text.find(word)
        end_index = start_index + len(word)
        print(f"Word: {word}\nStart: {start_index}\nEnd: {end_index}\n")
```

This outputs:

```
Word: car
Start: 16
End: 19

Word: red
Start: 12
End: 15

Word: green
Start: 66
End: 71
```

The code is actually pretty simple.

Line 1 and 2 define our text and our array.
Line 3 starts a for loop that loops for every element in the word list.
Line 4 checks to see if the word is in the text.
If it is, then line 5 gets the start index.
Line 6 gets the end index by adding the length of the word to the start index.
Finally, line 7 prints the information in a neat format.